# How to do a general reduce for all key/value pairs in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop and I try to execute some map/reduce tasks in Java . I was wondering how can we execute a reduce operation for all the key/value pairs .

For example imagine we have  for each day of a month the highest temperature in this current day . We take the day as a key and the temperature as a value and I wish to get the key/value for the highest temperature for all the month .

I hope my question is clear !

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just configure your job to use a single reducer via [job.setNumReduceTasks(1)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setNumReduceTasks%28int%29). This single reducer will iterate over all key/value pairs. In the `reduce()` method you just search for the maximum and in the `cleanup()` method you output the final result. Example with `(k, v) = (year, temperature)`:

```
public class MaxTemperatureReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, DoubleWritable, IntWritable, DoubleWritable> {
    private static int year = 0;
    private static double maxTemp = 0.0;

    @Override
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (DoubleWritable value : values) {
            if (value.get() > maxTemp) {
                year = key.get();
                maxTemp = value.get();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(new IntWritable(year), new DoubleWritable(maxTemp));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach would be to simply use an arbitrary key ("month") and have both temperature and day in the value - then in your reduce method, find the highest value for temperature and return both day and temperature.